# Did I simplify the boolean expression correctly?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I wanted someone to check and make sure that I did this right, I'm hoping that I did but if I didn't, please point me in the right direction of where I went wrong

[image: Simplifying the boolean expression]

Comment: It would be better if you could type it out your solution.

Comment: The fifth line is erroneous. $xyz+x'yz' \neq (x+x')(yz+yz')$

Comment: alright thank you so from there would I do this?

Comment: $(x'yz + xy) + (xy + xyz')$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}&\rm y(x'z+xz')+x(yz+yz')
\\ =\quad &\rm y(x'z+xz')+xy(z+z')&& \text{Distribution}
\\ =\quad &\rm y(x'z+xz')+xy(1)&& \text{Complementation (/Inversion)}
\\ =\quad &\rm x'yz+xyz'+xy &&\text{Distribution and Identity.}
\end{align}$

You were okay up to here, then you went all agley.   Instead, the next step should be to distribute out the $y$ factor.

$\begin{align}=\quad &\rm y(x'z+xz'+x) &&\text{Distribution}
\end{align}$

From here your path to the destination should be obvious.

Comment: Okay so my thoughts are get rid of the x or try to get rid of z but x might be easier right?

Comment: $\rm xz'+x = \underline\quad$

Comment: 'agley' ... learned a new word today! :)

Comment: $\begin{align}\quad &\rm xz' + x = x &&\text{Absorption Law}
\end{align}$

Comment: @AceNinja1101 Indeed.

Comment: so there's not much we can do after this right?
$\begin{align}=\quad &\rm y(x'z+x) &&
\end{align}$

Comment: Just distribution, disjunctive complementation, and conjunctive identity.

Comment: Okay so im having a brain fart and come to the answer -_-